# using eq() to fadeIn/Out list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of list items that I would like to fadeIn() and fadeOut() using eq(). I am also having trouble with posting so sorry if my code looks terrible!

```
<ul id="skater_mulitivew">
  <li class="first_gallery"></li>
  <li class="second_gallery"></li>
  <li class="third_gallery"></li>
  <li class="fourth_gallery"></li>
</ul>
```

and my jQuery/JS :

```
<script>
    $('.right_trigger').click(function(event) { 
      var i=0;
      event.preventDefault();
       while (i<5) { 
         $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(0).fadeOut('slow');
         $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(1).fadeOut('slow');
         i++;
       };
     });
</script>
```

It runs once, but doesn't run again when I re-click the .right_trigger item. I want to cycle through each list item on every click. Thanks for any input!

Comment: You can have `i` anywhere but set it to 0 just before the `while`

Comment: Why the var i and the loop? Fading out 5 times in a row is the same as fading just once. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Short answer: yes. The definition of `i` should be right before the `while`.

Comment: Yes, you are placing the var to far outside. But you can also reset i to 0 when you click.

Comment: Also, there is a syntax error, an extra `)` after closing the while block.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you are trying to achieve. Is the idea that each click will fade _out_ two items and fade _in_ the next two items, cycling through them repeatedly with multiple clicks?

Comment: Make sure to remove hash in html... `<ul id="#skater_mulitivew">` should be `<ul id="skater_mulitivew">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current Code Issues

---

`i` has global scope so the next time the loop tries to iterate `i` = 5, which causes the loop not to iterate.  Move the declaration for `i` into the anonymous function.

```
$('.right_trigger').click(function(event) { 
var i=0;
  event.preventDefault();
   while (i<5) { 
     $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(0).fadeOut('slow');
     $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(1).fadeOut('slow');
     i++;
   });
 });
```

### Optimization of Current Code

---

On a side note, I'm not sure why you call the `fadeOut()` function 5x.  You could achieve the same effect with:

```
$('.right_trigger').click(function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
     //If your trying to fadeout all li use the proceeding commented code
     //$('#skater_mulitivew li").fadeOut("slow");

     //If your actually trying to target by index use the proceeding code
     $('#skater_mulitivew li:eq(0),#skater_mulitivew li:eq(1) ').fadeOut('slow');
     i++;
 });
```

### Carousel Implementation

---

Given the comments it appears you want to make a carousel like feature.  Here is the html, css and javascript to make that happen.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="skater_mulitivew">
  <li class="first_gallery">Gallery 1</li>
  <li class="second_gallery">Gallery 2</li>
  <li class="third_gallery">Gallery 3</li>
  <li class="fourth_gallery">Gallery 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="right_trigger">Trigger</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#skater_mulitivew li{
    display:none;
}

#skater_mulitivew li:first-child{
    display: block;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
   $('.right_trigger').click(function(event) { 
      var items = $("#skater_mulitivew li");
      toggle(items,0);
   });

function toggle(items, index){

        items.eq(index).fadeOut('slow', function(){
               index = (index == items.length -1) ? -1:index;
               items.eq(index + 1).fadeIn('slow', function(){

               toggle(items, ++index); 
            });   
        });
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/njxnN/1/

Comment: Better yet, remove `i` and the `while`. I don't see any good reason to keep them.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, I was getting to that.

Comment: @KevinBowersox So in this case I'm not using i as a variable, but i as the index of the list items? Does your example allow for it to fade in and out each until it reaches the last list item?

Comment: @SkipZepeda A little confused about what you want to do? So when they click the trigger you want to fadeout every other li and fadein every other li?  Or do you want to display one at a time and when the click occurs hide the current and fade in the next?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I wanted to fadeOut the first list, replace it with the second, and then repeat that until I reach the last list, which should fadeOut and fadeIn the first indexed list.

Comment: @SkipZepeda Almost like a carousel?

Comment: @KevinBowersox exactly like a carousel. I have to make this as dynamic as possible so I can just put content inside the list items and cycle through them.

Comment: @SkipZepeda See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njxnN/  If it fits your needs i'll post as answer.

Comment: @KevinBowersox your jsfiddle is very useful and it's definitely pointing me in the right direction, thank you for your help!

Comment: @SkipZepeda Yep Give me a minute or so

Comment: @SkipZepeda Thanks for accepting, here is one that works off of clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/bU8kN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Definately it will work once because `1` `0` already fade out

```
<script>
    var i=0;

    $('.right_trigger').click(function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
       while (i<5) { 
         var next = i + 1;
         $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(i).fadeOut('slow');
         $('#skater_mulitivew li').eq(next).fadeOut('slow');
         i = i + 2;
       }
     });
</script>
```

You should also correct this in your html `<ul id="#skater_mulitivew">` to `<ul id="skater_mulitivew">`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yqaKW/1/)**

Comment: Now since I want the 'next" item to fadeIn, changing the method to .fadeIn() should work? Is this going to only work for the i and i+ 1 indexed items, or will this work for eq(2), eq(3), etc?

Comment: It's a loop, In 1st iteration it will fadeOut `0,1` in the 2nd iteration it will fadeOut `2,3`

Answer (score 0):

Yes your `i` is set globally and such is outside the bound of your while conditional when it gets called again.

Comment: So because I need to check for i < 5, it needs to increment and then re-declare that i=1, i=2, etc...?

Comment: Since i is declared outside of your function it will never be reset. So after the first click event is registered, your while loop will increment i up to 5 and then each subsequent click it will still be at 5. You need to move the i declaration inside the function body so that it creates a new i on each click, which I think is what your are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is not doing what you think it should be doing with the while loop, but your main problem is actually syntax error.

```
<ul id="#skater_mulitivew">
```

should be

```
<ul id="skater_mulitivew">
```

Note the extraneous hash.

```
       });
 });
```

Should be

```
       }
 });
```

Note the extraneous parenthesis and semi-colon.

Fixing these two errors will cause the first two `li` items to fade on clicking.

Comment: In your example, the } encapsulated the while (i<5) { portion?